# Google column chart does not display labels at X axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Issue:

All column charts are drawing properly in IE. However,

When I click the button "View Build Performances", it shows project names in x axis of first 3 column charts. It does not show project names in x axis of other column charts. If I click the button again, then it shows project names in x axis of all other column charts.

How to resolve this issue? I need all x axis labels to be displayed for all column charts when i click "View Build Performances".

Code is attached.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>


<script>
        //resource files and constants
        var csvFile="averages.csv";

        var options = {
                vAxis: { baseline: 0, viewWindowMode: "explicit", title: 'Build times in seconds', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}},
                hAxis: {title: 'Project names',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}}

        };

        google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
        //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


        //create display area for each row of chart
        function createDiv(id) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.id = id;
            div.style.width="100%";
            div.style.height="60%";
            document.body.appendChild(div);
        }


        //draw column charts
        function drawChart() {

            // grab the CSV
            $.get(csvFile, function(csvString) {

                    //transform the CSV string into a 2-dimensional array
                    var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

                    // this new DataTable object holds all the data
                    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

                    var barChart = new Array();
                    var view = new Array();
                    var chart_index =0;

                    var selected_column_indexes=[0,1,2,3,4];

                    var rows=[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,10,11],[12,13,14],[15,16,17],[18,19,20]];

                    while(chart_index < rows.length)
                    {
                        //creating div area to display chart
                        var divId = 'chart_div'+chart_index;
                        if(!document.getElementById(divId))
                            createDiv(divId);

                        // this view can select a subset of the data at a time

                        view[chart_index] = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
                        view[chart_index].setColumns(selected_column_indexes);
                        view[chart_index].setRows(rows[chart_index]);

                        barChart[chart_index] = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(divId));
                        barChart[chart_index].draw(view[chart_index], options);

                        //barChart[chart_index] = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById(divId));
                        //barChart[chart_index].draw(view[chart_index], options);

                        chart_index++;
                    }

            });


        }//end draw chart


</script>
```

```
<table align='center'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="View Build Performances" id="viewBP" onclick="drawChart()"/> 
        </td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

```
averages.csv

Project,R7.0d.PASB,R8.1a.PASB,R9.0f.PASB,R9.1a.PASB
r6.1067.clean,11.96,11.27,10.61,10.69
r6.BUe_Sittertal_GAW.clean,15.95,16.05,16.26,15.92
r6.GE_Machine.clean,19.10,19.05,18.96,19.86
r6.Haringvlietsluis.clean,19.58,22.73,24.05,23.68
r6.M411_11450_PB.clean,8.07,8.04,7.65,7.52
r6.PSS4000_Wand_Fabrik_SPS2010_V5.clean,3.93,4.03,4.08,4.10
r6.Sichere_Bewegung_V2.clean,3.47,3.48,3.41,3.53
r6.Testprojekt_V111.clean,82.82,46.79,42.30,41.88
r6.TruBend3000_V1010_3.clean,10.50,10.35,9.71,9.80
r6.Volkerak_Brug.clean,11.89,12.21,11.93,11.90
r7.25000_30.clean,357.07,339.55,283.64,280.08
r7.ALB_WRT2_L4_SIRE.pcfix,43.82,45.15,46.71,44.76
r7.BougnonneV5.clean,17.59,16.96,16.48,16.32
r7.FT_IL_LOOP_PMI.visu,5.08,4.80,4.98,4.97
r7.FT_IL_LOOP_PMI.visudeleted,4.67,4.53,4.80,4.79
r7.Ferrero_IL.visu,101.34,110.86,112.79,104.82
r7.Ferrero_IL.visudeleted,93.84,105.74,107.96,101.68
r7.Ferrero_STL.visu,99.52,110.66,114.50,103.62
r7.Ferrero_STL.visudeleted,93.35,105.99,109.72,103.00
r7.Ferrero_v0_5.visu,159.30,174.80,242.50,141.06
r7.Ferrero_v0_5.visudeleted,140.86,142.29,204.28,127.67
r7.Festo_R7_Network.clean,13.98,13.33,14.61,14.19
r7.Fischer_Techniks_Multi.clean,4.47,4.39,4.70,4.53
r7.Les_Avants.clean,98.21,96.82,106.38,105.49
r8.12045.visu,0,61.27,21.16,21.71
r8.1279_DST.clean,0,139.35,109.44,103.19
r8.Antriebstation.clean,0,55.65,30.97,30.78
r8.Doppelmayr_Komplett.clean,0,0,460.32,466.59
r8.LSBEmmettenNiederbauen.visu,0,0,86.00,80.64
r8.LSBEmmettenNiederbauen.visudeleted,0,0,71.77,70.94
r8.P8560_Blk56_FixPlc_new.clean,0,0,36.54,36.21
r8.Securite_TS.clean,0,0,81.43,74.86
```

Comment: You need to simplify your code to reduce it down to a basic example that demonstrates the problem.  As-is, your code is too complex to reasonably expect others to diagnose (and is dependent on CSV files on your server, so we can't test it).  As a starting point, I suggest removing the `$(document).ready` calls that are inside `drawChart`; the code inside them should run just fine (and because of the asynchronous nature of loading the Visualization API, it is possible to finish loading after document ready fires, ensuring that your event handlers never get a chance to fire).

Comment: I simplified the code and csv file has been added. could someone show me the issue? thanks.

Comment: I suspect that your project names are too long to fit in the available space (though this is difficult to tell, since you do not specify dimensions for the chart).  See [narrow chart](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/GqJ8R/) vs [wide chart](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/GqJ8R/).

Comment: You can fix this by making the charts wider, adding spaces to the project titles (so they will line break automatically), increasing the height of the charts (so the labels can be drawn at an angle), or play around with the `hAxis` options for labels (`slantedText`, `slantedTextAngle`, `maxAlternation`, `maxTextLines`, `minTextSpacing`).  Some combination of these options might be required to suit your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I had to deal with it for a while, so for those still using this, here is my solution

I had this, and the column names where not showing up.

```
chartArea: {
  left: 80,
  top: 10,
  width: '100%',
  height: '90%'
},
```

And I changed for this

```
 chartArea: {
  left: 80,
  top: 10,
  width: '100%',
  height: '70%'
},
```

As you can see, the **height** was to big.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
 hAxis: {
     textPosition: 'none'
 }
```